# GSON - Deserialize java generics collection

Tags: gson

I am trying to deserialize an arraylist from the DB withiout a success.
this is the way I put my objects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dealsList.size(); i++) {
    ServerServicesInternalWrapper.reportDeal(Json.toWrap(dealsList.get(i)));
}
```

where

```
public static <T> String toWrap(T t) {
    JsonWrapperWithType wrapper = 
        new JsonWrapperWithType(t.getClass(),gson.toJson(t));
    return to(wrapper);
}
```

this is the way I select

```
return (List<DealBean>)session.createCriteria(DealBean.class).add(Restrictions.eq("portfolio", portfolio)).list();
```

and then I Gson it to a string using

```
JsonWrapperWithType wrapper = 
    new JsonWrapperWithType(t.getClass(), gson.toJson(t));
return gson.toJson(wrapper );
```

and this is the way I de-gson the object
And now - the exception

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<DealBean>>(){}.getType();

List<DealBean> dealsForPortfolio =
    (List<DealBean>)gson.fromJson(dealsForPortfolioString,type);


com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer 
com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@1f899e9 failed to deserialized 
json object {"type":"java.util.ArrayList","content":"[{\"ID\":5,\"tradable\":
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
```

Comment: Is this still open issue?  If so, what's the value of dealsForPortfolioString?  It looks like it's not JSON of the structure the code expected it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Gson expects a list of Json objects like: `[{obj1}, {obj2}, ... , {objN}]`

I'm not sure from code you posted here what your intentions were but it seems to me like you are wrapping a list with parent object.

In the case you want it like that, you need to make your own [deserializer](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ).